# JST v Underscore Templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, jst

I'm playing around with a demo Rails Backbone app that uses JST templates. In the user_ registration view, it has a line like this

```
template: JST["users/signup"],
```

that refers to the signup template, part of which has a form with a `user_registration` id

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="simple_form form-horizontal" id="user_registration" method="post">
```

If you click submit on the form, the user registration view calls a signup function

```
events: {
        "submit #user_registration" : "signup"
    },
```

Importantly, the user registration view does not explicitly declare an `el`. I assume that's important because the `el` usually defines the territory in which the view listens for events. In this view, it's not declared, but it knows when the submit button is clicked.

If I remove the line

```
   template: JST["users/signup"],
```

and copy the code from that template (including the #user_registration id) into an underscore template, and then tell the user_registration view, in its initialization, to use that template like this

```
  var template = $('#signup').html();
  this.template = _.template(template);
```

once I click submit on the #user_registration form, the user_registration view no longer hears that event.

In summary, the user_registration view only hears the submit event when I'm using `template: JST["users/signup"],` for templating, not when I use underscore. In neither case, do I explicitly declare the territory in which the view should be listening with `el`. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can recreate a folder with user templates on jsfiddle that would respond to this, template: JST["users/signup"]

Comment: But `JST` is just an object full of JavaScript functions.

Comment: To explain @muistooshort you can simply copy your _compiled_ JST template into fiddle. You can also easily find out which element on the page your view is hooking up with by just `console.log(this.$el)` you know…

Comment: With a router and need for many stubs, I can't get a fiddle to reproduce problem. However, if anyone desires this is someone else's Rails app with Backbone implementing Devise. If I take the JST templates and put them in script tags  to use underscore as described in OP, then it doesn't work. https://github.com/paulociecomp/backbone-devise